# Spread on x-axis around an extremum

Tags: probability, variance, standard-deviation

I am working on a graph that has Power (Watts) on the x-axis and Frequency (not Hertz here, more like the probability that we consume that much power) on the y-axis.

What I would like to do with it is find the maximas which is not particularly challenging. But the second info I would like to find is the spread around these maximas, in other words how much can we deviate from this "probable" state (probable in the sense if it is a maxima means it has high probability for this value).

Just as an example let's consider a television that has a very stable consumption. When you turn it on it consumes X Watts, but the consumptions varies around the "mean" value. Thus I'd like to find out the interval in which this television's consumption varies using my Probability (on y-axis) and Power (on x-axis) graph.

Maybe my research on the internet was unsuccessful because I lack the statistical vocabulary about what I'm searching. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Extreme value modeling is a well developed field in statistics. What is your unit of analysis? Your example of tv sets suggests that 'devices' are the unit and watt consumption is the metric. By defining a tail area or upper bound to consumption, you can create a set of "block maxima" for your data that would facilitate your analysis.

Here are some useful links to reading on EVT:

Intro to EVT
http://www.stat.unc.edu/faculty/rs/talks/AMS2009.pdf

Block Maxima Models
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3222.pdf